# UWP How to get a NavigationView inner shadow projected by the content pane?

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Looking at the UWP navigation view documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview,  I see multiple examples where the NavigationView has an inner shadow on the right side, projected by the content frame (see images below).

Is there a way to reproduce this style? By trying the examples of NavigationView available in the documentation and project examples, I get something different, where the left pane is the one projecting a shadow on the right side (when the navigation view is open), which is the exact opposite.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the reason you are trying to fight the default behavior? The navigation pane is the UI element the user is interacting with. The shadow conveys that the navigation pane is in the foreground. Having the content cast a shadow onto the navigation pane seems counterintuitive.

Comment: My goal isn't to fight the default behaviour. I appreciate the style from the documentation examples, and would like to understand how to replicate it.

Comment: As @IInspectable said, the shadow represents the navigation pane is in the foreground, this is by design. It is not feasible to add shadow on the content part.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Ok, thanks for the response. So that means that the documentation isn't correct.

Comment: Yes, but this needs to confirm, I will report to the team.

Comment: Cool, that's good to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/depth-shadow

```
<Grid>
   <Grid x:Name="Sidebar" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}" />

   <Frame x:Name="Frame" Translation="0,0,10">
      <Windows10version1903:Frame.Shadow>
          <ThemeShadow x:Name="Shadow"/>
      </Windows10version1903:Frame.Shadow>
   </Frame>
</Grid>
Shadow.Receivers.Add(Sidebar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the WinUI NavigationView control, you can also hack around it to add the required ThemeShadows where necessary, but it's a bit more involved if you also want to keep the stock shadow behavior in Overlay mode:

*Page.xaml*

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavigationView" Loaded="ApplyShadowToSideBar">
   <!-- Your navView content --> 
   <Grid>
         <Grid.Shadow>
              <ThemeShadow x:Name="ContentShadow" />
         </Grid.Shadow>
   </Grid>
</NavigationView>
```

*Page.xaml.cs:*

```csharp
private void ApplyShadowToSideBar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Some VisualTree hacking to get the content grid for left display mode and cast shadows over it
    // Names of the ControlTemplates taken from https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/NavigationView/docs/rendering.md#displaymode-left
    Grid rootGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(NavigationView, 0) as Grid;
    if (rootGrid != null)
    {
        // Get the pane's grid, which receives all our shadows
        var paneContentGrid = rootGrid.FindName("PaneContentGrid") as Grid;

        // Shadow emitters for the header. The header has grids for both its content and top padding, so we need to shadow up both of them.
        var headerContent = rootGrid.FindName("HeaderContent") as ContentControl;
        var headerTopContent = rootGrid.FindName("ContentTopPadding") as Grid;
        var headerShadow = new ThemeShadow();
        var headerTopShadow = new ThemeShadow();

        // Remove default HeaderContent margin so the shadow can be cast correctly.
        // You can set NavigationViewHeaderMargin again in your own content to match.
        headerContent.Margin = new Thickness(0);

        // Set receivers
        headerShadow.Receivers.Add(paneContentGrid);
        headerTopShadow.Receivers.Add(paneContentGrid);
        ContentShadow.Receivers.Add(paneContentGrid);

        headerContent.Shadow = headerShadow;
        headerContent.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 32);

        headerTopContent.Shadow = headerTopShadow;
        headerTopContent.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 32);

        shellFrame.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 32);
    }
}
```

If you're using a Header for the NavigationView, you'll have to add a margin to it manually, and make sure to remove said margin when the NavView is in Minimal mode so you don't get extra whitespace.